# Java: Converting a String into an Int recursively?

Tags: java, string, recursion, int

I'm trying to create a Java program that converts a String into an Integer recursively. This is currently what I have but it gives me an error, "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException". The method is supposed to take in a number in the form of a string then iterate through each position. Through each iteration it turns the single number into a integer and adds it to x. By the end of it x is suppose to have the String number in integer form.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

`public class Problem{

    public static int x=0;
    public static int integer;

    public static int intconvert(String numb,int index,int times){
        if(index==numb.length()){
            return x;
        }
        else{
            integer=Integer.parseInt("numb.charAt(index)"); //
            x+=integer*times;   //add int and multiply it
            return intconvert(numb, index++, times*10);  // 
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the String digit: ");
        String number=scan.nextLine();
        intconvert(number, 0, 1);
        /*   System.out.println(number.charAt(0));
        System.out.println(number.charAt(1));
        System.out.println(number.charAt(2));*/
    }
}`

Comment: You are passing a non parsable string. remove quotes around `numb.charAt(index)`.

Comment: Why is everyone suddenly implementing recursive versions of all the things which are better implemented via simple iteration? (I know, it's early in the term and they just learned about recursion and think it's cool and don't understand when it is and isn't appropriate. None the less: _grrrrrrr_. End rant.)

Comment: I've been exposed. This is just an exercise to help me understand recursion. There really is no practical purpose for this code and i'm sure simple iteration would easily solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if the method was correct, i.e:

```
public static int intconvert(String numb, int index, int times) {
        if (index == numb.length()) { return x; }
        integer = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(numb.charAt(index))); //
        x += integer * times; // add int and multiply it
        return intconvert(numb, index++, times * 10); //

    }
```

You'll still get an StackOverFlow exception, because you of the way you increment your x, it will never enter the stopping condition.

If I understood what you wanted to do, the solution is:

```
public class Cenas {

    public static int x = 0;
    public static int integer;

    public static int intconvert(String numb, int index, int times) {
        integer = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(numb.charAt(index))); //
        x += integer * times; // add int and multiply it
        if (index == 0) { return x; }
        return intconvert(numb, --index, times * 10); //

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the String digit: ");
        String number = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println(intconvert(number, number.length() - 1, 1));
}
```

Start at the algarism with the less weight and work your way to the beggining index, also you were missing the print statement at your main call.

Because you are incrementing your "times" 10 times by each iteration you must start ate the last index of the string.

Example:
123 = 1 * 100 + 2 * 10 + 3 * 1

Your problem was not recursion but the algorithm you were using.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. Any suggestions to increment the x?

Comment: I would have to understand the purpose of the method, because right now I dont understand why not call Integer.parseInt(string_that_represents_a_number), the way you described your problem makes me thinkthat recursion is not needed, a simple loop will do it.

Comment: There really is no reason. It's just an Exercise in a book of mine to help me understand recursion through practice problems.

Comment: Did I understand what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, you've nailed it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
integer=Integer.parseInt(numb.charAt(index));
```

won't work, because `charAt()` returns a `char`, and `parseInt` expects a `String`. Try converting that `char` into a `String` with `Character.toString(c)`:

```
Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(numb.charAt(index)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
integer = Integer.parseInt(numb.substring(index, index +  1)); //
index++;
```

Instead of:

```
integer=Integer.parseInt("numb.charAt(index)");
```

And remove `++` of `index++` from `return intconvert(numb, index++, times * 10);` its not increase passed `index`.

Answer (score 0):

Numbers are sequential in their ascii values, so in order to turn your `char` into an `int`, you could simply do:

```
int integer = numb.charAt(index) - '0';
```

all that is left is to ensure that `integer` is between bounds and your function should work just fine.

by the way, I would remove the static global variables. If you simply pass them as parameters instead, your solution will be "pure", as in side-effect free or [referentially transparent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency_%28computer_science%29)

Answer (score -2):

Try changing

```
integer=Integer.parseInt("numb.charAt(index)");
```

into

```
integer=Integer.parseInt(numb.substring(index, index + 1));
```

The original line tries to find a number within the string `"numb.charAt(index)"`, which doesn't contain any numbers.

**Also**, change `index++` to `index + 1` or even `++index`, since `index++` has no effect in this case (it only increments `index` after it's been used, and just before it goes out of scope.

Comment: numb.charAt(index)) returns a char